# android get Colour

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello i have lots of button with the same OnClickListener, the buttons have different colours, how can i get the colour(or the colour resource) of the pressed button ?

Here is the code i use

```
// declare a OnClickListener that will execute different actions
        // depending on the view that was clicked
        View.OnClickListener colorButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void  onClick  (View  v){
                textarea_note.setBackgroundDrawable(v.getBackground());//set edit background the same of the button
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        };

        Button button1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button3 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button button4 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button button5 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button button6 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button6);
        Button button7 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button7);
        Button button8 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button8);
        Button button9 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button9);


        /*for changing the colour when the user clicks on a button*/
        button1.setOnClickListener(colorButtonListener);
        button2.setOnClickListener(colorButtonListener);
        button3.setOnClickListener(colorButtonListener);
        button4.setOnClickListener(colorButtonListener);
        button5.setOnClickListener(colorButtonListener);
        button6.setOnClickListener(colorButtonListener);
        button7.setOnClickListener(colorButtonListener);
        button8.setOnClickListener(colorButtonListener);
        button9.setOnClickListener(colorButtonListener);


        /**for the round corner*/
        Resources res = this.getResources();
        button1.setBackgroundDrawable(this.Sd(res.getColor(R.color.color1x1)));
        button2.setBackgroundDrawable(this.Sd(res.getColor(R.color.color1x2)));
        button3.setBackgroundDrawable(this.Sd(res.getColor(R.color.color1x3)));
        button4.setBackgroundDrawable(this.Sd(res.getColor(R.color.color2x1)));
        button5.setBackgroundDrawable(this.Sd(res.getColor(R.color.color2x2)));
        button6.setBackgroundDrawable(this.Sd(res.getColor(R.color.color2x3)));
        button7.setBackgroundDrawable(this.Sd(res.getColor(R.color.color3x1)));
        button8.setBackgroundDrawable(this.Sd(res.getColor(R.color.color3x2)));
        button9.setBackgroundDrawable(this.Sd(res.getColor(R.color.color3x3)));



        //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it    
        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, You can get the color values(for eg: R.color.green) but you can get a drawable object of the button.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Drawable d = v.getBackground()
            }
        });
```

Comment: you have a mispeled error? yes but once i have the Drawable how do i extract the color in string form, or color id or anything that i can use to save to a file and the read and apply to an EditText, thanks

Comment: Misspelled error is useless, you can disable it. Now for using: you can save the drawable file itself and set it is as the background of any view you want. But i am afraid that you can get the  color id OR any string form from this drawable object.

Comment: do you mean "you can't get the color id OR..." or you "can get the color id OR..."

Comment: sorry for the typo. You cant get the color id or string form

Answer (score 0):

I've found this method, but i have never try it :

```
   int color = v.getSolidColor();
```

Comment: this function "Returns
The known solid color background for this view, or 0 if the color may vary "
i always get 0 :(

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtColor);
txt.setText("Color Of Button ");
View.OnClickListener colorButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void  onClick  (View  v){
            txt.setTextColor(v.getSolidColor());
            textarea_note.setBackgroundDrawable(v.getBackground());//set edit background the same of the button
            dialog.dismiss();
            Log.i("Color of Button","Color = "+v.getSolidColor() );
        }
    };
```

Note : follow this link : [getSolidColor()](http://www.mediafire.com/?zw5r256ojm5wod4)

in your Code , try to replace the :

```
button1.setBackgroundDrawable(this.Sd(res.getColor(R.color.color1x1)));
```

with :

```
button1.setBackgroundRessource(R.color.color1x1);
```

download this project , i've created 4 buttons, and i get the color of the background ;) , enjoy it

[Get Color of Buttons](http://www.mediafire.com/?zw5r256ojm5wod4)

Hope it helps

Comment: 05-18 10:19:51.279: INFO/Color of Button(4832): Color = 0
05-18 10:19:41.408: INFO/Color of Button(4832): Color = 0
, i tried, yet for different colors i get always color = 0

Comment: okey , so you can't get the Color id i think , 
 but you can try to Add a TextView in your Application , and change the TextColor of it in function of the Button Clicked , see my edit post again

Comment: dunno, doesn't work, gives me invocation error, i think i'll just a gigantic switch on v.getId()

Comment: thanks a lot :D, but txt.setBackgroundDrawable(v.getBackground());
this i had already in my code working, while txt.setTextColor(v.getSolidColor()); doesn't do a thing, and i still didn't get the actual color i only have this view object that i don't know where to put it ...

Comment: that's what i got my friend , i've never work with getSoldColor(), 
as i understand , u want to get the color of the Background of your Buttons, and display it , 
so that's what i've done on the project , :)

Comment: no that i already did :D what i want is to get the color in hex or string format in order to able to save it in a file and then load it... i'm affraid you misunderstood me xD, but thanks anyway for the big dedication of time